# Page needs refreshing to remove deleted data

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to programming and I hope someone can help me with my problem.
Why does my page needs to refresh to render the removed data in database?

I tried searching the net to find someone whith the same problem, but I couldn't find any

Here's my code

delete.php

```
class DELETE{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_DATABASE,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
    }

    public function deletePromo($id){
        $sql="DELETE FROM `promo` WHERE `id` = :id";
        $q = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
        return true;
    }
```

delete modal

```
<?php 
    include_once '../utils/delete.php';

    $obj = new DELETE;

    if(isset($_REQUEST['del_id'])){
        if($obj->deletePromo($_REQUEST['del_id'],"promo")){
        }
    }
?>
<?php
    echo '</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-primary" id="delete"><a href="promo.php?del_id=' . $data2['id'] . '" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">Delete</a></button>';
?>
```

Comment: You want to automatically refresh the particular content without refreshing the page ?

Comment: Basically it refresh after pressing the delete button because of the href. The problem is the removed data is still in the page and I need to refresh the page to remove the deleted data in my page.

Comment: You can have like this,, The new data to set in a div with an `id` and the old data should be in another `id` then you can just `hide` and `show` using jquery

Comment: I tried already tried hiding it with a simple js code but nothing happens. can you give me some codes? i'm just new in this languages that's why i'm having a hard time dealing with problems like this >.<

Comment: You are probably putting the `select` query before the `delete` query. You need to fetch the data after the delete query has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a workaround something like this

1. In the `index.php` or the page where you have the login form

Check whether you set the session, If so take the user to the page like dashboard or home page that you have else show the login form

**Here' the Sample, and you can change it accordingly to your wish**

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['yoursession'])) 
{
header('Location: dashboard.php');
#Take the uer to Home Page
}
else
{
?>
Show the Login Form
<?php
}
?>
```

2. In Other Page such as `dashboard.php`

Check whether the session is set, If so show the page else take the user to the login page back

**And here's the Logic**

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['yoursession'])) 
{
?>
Show Your Page
<?php
}
else
header('Location: login.php');
#Take the uer to Login Page
}
?>
```